# How to clear a textbox in asp.net?

Tags: c#, webforms, textbox

I tried `TextBox1.Clear` but it doesn't work and gives me error.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        TextBox1.Clear
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is totally unclear what you asking. Sounds like you just need `TextBox1.text = null`. But please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this way,

```
TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be one way to do it:

```
TextBox1.Text = string.Empty;
```